# python: amicable numbers check

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function in python that tells me if two numbers (m,n) are amicable or not.
I know that amicable numbers are two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number.

I can't get pass from here

```
def ami_check(m,n):
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: To solve this, define a function that calculates sum of divisors of a single number (since you need to do that twice). Hint: the function will have a loop checking for every integer of the appropriate range if it is a divisor of the given number or not.

Answer (score 4):

Definition, `Amicable Numbers` from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers):

> Amicable numbers are two different numbers so related that the sum of
>   the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. (A proper
>   divisor of a number is a positive factor of that number other than the
>   number itself.

Break that down:

1. `two different numbers`   OK
2. `the sum of the proper divisors of each`    OK
3. `is equal to the other number` OK

Then:

```
def ami_check(x,y):
    if x==y: return False                              # 1
    sum_x=sum(e for e in range(1, x//2+1) if x%e==0)   # 2
    sum_y=sum(e for e in range(1, y//2+1) if y%e==0)   # 2
    return sum_x==y and sum_y==x                       # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Using this Code ::
for check the amicable numbers

```
def sumPropDiv(n):
    """returns sum of proper divisors of n"""
    dSum = 0
    for x in range(1, n/2 + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            dSum += x
    return dSum

def amicSum(number):
    """finds the sum of all amicable numbers less than number, with number greater than 4."""
    answer = 0
    for x in range(4, number):
        if sumPropDiv(x) > 4:
            if sumPropDiv(sumPropDiv(x)) == x and sumPropDiv(x) != x:
                answer += x
                print x, "and", sumPropDiv(x), "are an amicable pair."
    return answer

print amicSum(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt,

```
def factors(n):    
        return sorted(reduce(list.__add__, 
                    ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))[:-1]

def ami_check(m,n):
    return sum(factors(m)) == n and n != m
```

**Result**

```
In [1]: ami_check(220,284)
Out[1]: True
In [2]: ami_check(5545,21654)
Out[2]: False
In [3]: ami_check(2620,2924)
Out[3]: True
```